# How to add search functionality on custom post type in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type

I have registered new custom post type in the function file. After that, I have created one new template and assigned that template on the page. Following code, I am using two display all records of my custom post type.

```
<?php
  $temp = $wp_query;
  $wp_query = null;
  $wp_query = new WP_Query();
  $wp_query->query('showposts=5&post_type=news'.'&paged='.$paged);

  while ($wp_query->have_posts()) : $wp_query->the_post();
?>

  <!-- LOOP: Usual Post Template Stuff Here-->

<?php endwhile; ?>

<nav>
    <?php previous_posts_link('&laquo; Newer') ?>
    <?php next_posts_link('Older &raquo;') ?>
</nav>

<?php
  $wp_query = null;
  $wp_query = $temp;  // Reset
?>
```

Now I want to add one search form which will be used to search on the post title and return results in the same page. I have no idea how to do this so can someone help for search.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a search filter in your functions that filters out your custom post type. Not tested but should work.

```
// Search Filter
add_filter('pre_get_posts','rusty_search_filter');
function rusty_search_filter($query) {
  if (!is_admin() && is_page('news')) {
    if ($query->is_search) {
      $query->set('post_type', array('news'));
    }
    return $query;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can include custom post types in Wordpress search results by adding the below code in the `functions.php` file.

```
 add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'tgm_io_cpt_search' );
    function tgm_io_cpt_search( $query ) {
        if ( $query->is_search ) {
           $query->set( 'post_type', array( 'post', 'news', 'products', 'portfolio') );
        }
        return $query;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Sample search form:

```
<div id="photo-search" class="search-box">
    <form method="POST" action="">
        <div>
            <input type="text" id="search" name="search" required="required" value="<?php echo isset($_POST['search']) ? $_POST['search'] : '' ?>"/>
            <span><button class="button" name="button">Search</button></span>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

add below code to your `class Example_List_Table extends WP_List_Table`

```
private function table_data()
{
    $args = array(
        's' => (isset($_POST['search'])) ? $_POST['search'] : '',
    );
    $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
}
```